# Javascript timestamp parsed as wrong date by Carbon in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime

I have the following code that stores the current timestamp in localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('visitedOn', new Date().getTime())
```

which sets the timestamp to `1586525864525` (today a few minutes ago)

When I make an API request to my Laravel backend, and parse the timestamp using

```
Carbon::createFromTimestamp($request->visitedOn)
```

It returns the following value, which is completely off.

```
Carbon @1104613325 {#993
  date: 2005-01-01 22:02:05.0 Europe/Brussels (+01:00)
}
```

Any idea what might be going wrong? Are there multiple types of timestamps with different character lengths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`createFromTimestamp` accepts a value in seconds and `new Date().getTime()` returns the time in milliseconds, so, you should use `createFromTimestampMs` that accepts the Unit timestamp in milliseconds.

```php
Carbon::createFromTimestampMs($request->visitedOn)
```